# is it possible to run geb-spock test on eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, junit, spock, geb

Using the junit runner, is it possible to run geb-spock test like a normal spock tests?

It seems that a stock eclipse installation can't do it and couldn't find any eclipse plugin to add the functionality.

I'm trying this using eclipse-oxygen latest.

Comment: Do you have the groovy plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

To run Geb-Spock tests like a normal Spock test. (I am thinking you mean without initializing a browser.) Just `extends Specification` instead of `extends GebSpec`. Spock uses jUnit as the default test runner. So a Eclipse plugin for jUnit should work with Spock.